# How do I get typeArguments?

Tags: scala, types

I was using `man.typeArguments` in some 2.9.2 code, but got a message that `Manifest`s are deprecated. I figured out how to use `typeOf[T]` to access the `<:<` method, but I can't for the life of me figure out where `typeArguments` has gone to.

For context, I'm writing a `createParser[T: TypeTag]` method. If `T` is a `List[X]` then I create its parser by chaining a list of `createParser[X]`. Or that's what I'd like to do, anyway.

Anybody know how I should get `X` from `T` (or `typeOf[T]` or `typeTag[T]` or any other conceivable `T`-adjacent concept?

Here's the code in 2.9.2:

```
  def getParser[T](implicit man: Manifest[T]): Parser[T] = {
    if (man <:< manifest[Stream[_]]) {
      val itemType = man.typeArguments(0)
      streamParser(itemType).asInstanceOf[Parser[T]]
    } else {
      parsers(man)().asInstanceOf[Parser[T]]
    }
  }

  def streamParser[T](implicit man: Manifest[T]): Parser[Stream[T]] = {
    val itemParser = getParser(man)
    (openParser("[") ~> repsep(itemParser, comma) <~ closeParser("]")) ^^ (_.toStream)
  }
```

Here's what I'm trying in 2.10.1, but not having much luck with:

```
  def getParser[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Parser[T] = {
    if (tag.tpe <:< typeOf[Stream[_]]) tag.tpe match {
      case TypeRef(_, _, List(itemType)) => streamParser(itemType).asInstanceOf[Parser[T]]
    } else {
      parsers(tag)().asInstanceOf[Parser[T]]
    }
  }

  def streamParser[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Parser[Stream[T]] = {
    val itemParser = getParser(tag)
    (openParser("[") ~> repsep(itemParser, comma) <~ closeParser("]")) ^^ (_.toStream)
  }
```

The problem is that it says `itemType` is a `Type` from the reflection API, but I can't figure out how to turn that into a `TypeTag` suitable for sending to `streamParser`.

That `parsers` value is actually a map from `TypeTag`s to `Parser`s, and it would probably be cleaner to just put everything into the `getParser` method and match on the type of the thing I want to parse, but my attempts at pattern matching on types haven't seemed to work so far.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this--I think I'm just caught between a new implementation and documentation that hasn't caught up to it.

Comment: Manifests are actually not yet deprecated, because Scala reflection is still experimental.

Comment: While that's officially true, their use does cause compiler warnings to appear.

Comment: Actually, it's just the `<:<` method that causes a deprecation warning, so I guess I'll stick with them until `TypeTag` can do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.10 (and even more in 2.11) the way to extract information out of types and trees is to use pattern matching, in this case with [`TypeRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types%24TypeRefExtractor):

```
scala> typeOf[List[Int]] match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }
res13: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(Int)

scala> typeOf[Map[Int, String]] match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }
res14: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(Int, String)

scala> val TypeRef(_, _, args) = typeOf[List[Int]] // slightly shorter
args: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(Int)
```

Comment: This looked like what I was looking for, and then I tried it, and it wasn't. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @TOB: What you want to do is not possible. Adding TypeTags is a compile time operation, you can't extract them at runtime and assume that the compiler knows them. I assume what you want is that your `parsers` is a `Map[Type, Parser[_]]`.

Comment: Except that it worked with `.typeArguments` and a `Manifest` in 2.9.2. So is something that was possible not possible anymore?

Comment: It is because `TypeTag` is not directly equivalent to `Manifest`. And a `TypeTag` and `Type` are two different things, which need to be handled in 2.10.

Comment: @TOB: You can solve your problem using this technique: https://github.com/scalamacros/kepler/blob/2f3a7fa417f7ba92251fdae53e5548f081c2fd04/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/StdCreators.scala#L16