# In Scala, how to use reflection to get the real type of varargs parameters for method

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm using reflection to get parameter type of method, but there is some problem with varargs. Here is my code:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

case class C() {
  def f(x: String*) = x
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val c = C()
    val r = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(c)
    val x = r.symbol.typeSignature.member(newTermName("f"))
    val params = x.asMethod.paramss.head.map {
      _.typeSignature.typeSymbol
    }
    for (param <- params) {
      println(param)
    }
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
> class <repeated>
```

How can I get the real type `String`? Or is there any way else to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_.typeSignature.typeArgs.head`, because `String` is a type argument of `String*`, not its `typeSymbol`.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I can't find method "typeArgs" in TypeSignature, I'm using scala 2.10

Comment: This method was added in 2.11. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15597707/9204 for a 2.10 alternative.

Comment: Works in 2.11! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter `x` is type of `String*`. That is what you get by calling:

```
_.typeSignature.typeSymbol
```

but `String*` is intrepreted as `Seq[String]` (as we all know). Thus calling:

```
_.typeSignature.typeArgs
```

will get you your type arguments, i.e. your desired `String`.
Btw. if you want to prove that `String*` is `Seq` just call:

```
_.typeSignature.erasure
```

So your modified code should look like (omitting class C):

```
val c = C()
val r = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(c)
val x = r.symbol.typeSignature.member(newTermName("f"))
val params = x.asMethod.paramss.head.map {
  _.typeSignature.typeArgs
}
for (param <- params) {
  println(param)
}
```

it will print `List(String)`.

Enjoy